# How to update angularjs.module.value with array and retrieving it through service?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update a global angularjs module.value in one controller with an array, and then retrieving that global array through in a  service. But the array doesn't exist.

**app.js**

```
  app.factory('featureClaims', function($q) {
    var featureClaims = {};

    featureClaims.init = function() {
        featureClaims.claims = [];
    }
    featureClaims.get = function() {
        return $q.when(featureClaims.claims);
    }
    featureClaims.set = function(data) {
        featureClaims.claims = data;
        return $q.when(featureClaims.claims); // I'm using the $q library to return a promise.
    }
    return featureClaims;
});
```

**loginController**

```
let loginController = function($scope, loginService, toastrObj, featureClaims) {
   $scope.login = function(){
            featureClaims.init();
            featureClaims.set(result.data.FeatureClaims); // updating ok here
   }
}

app.controller("loginController", ["$scope", 'loginService', 'toastrObj', 'featureClaims',loginController]);
```

**home service**

```
let homeService= function(featureClaims) {   // featureClaims.claims is null
    return{
        validateUser: function(expectedClaim) {
            if(expectedClaim !== ""){
                featureClaims.get().then(function(data){
                    return data.includes(expectedClaim);  // data is return as undefined
                })
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
};
app.factory('homeService',['featureClaims', homeService]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a value service this way. From [this post](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/) the author states: "Note: Make sure that you never overwrite the value service/object as a whole otherwise your assignment is lost. Always reassign the property values of the value object. The following assignment is wrong and does not lead to the expected behavior"

Instead why don't you convert your value to a factory like so:

```
app.factory('featureClaims', function($q) {
    var featureClaims = {};

    featureClaims.init = function() {
        featureClaims.claims = [];
    }

    featureClaims.get = function() {
        return $q.when(featureClaims.claims); 
    }

    featureClaims.set = function(data) {
        featureClaims.claims = data;
        return $q.when(featureClaims.claims); // I'm using the $q library to return a promise.
    }
    return featureClaims;
});
```

In your controller:

```
featureClaims.init();
// you need to wait for the promise to resolve with 'then'
featureClaims.set(['foo', 'bar']).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response); // logs ["foo", "bar"]
});

featureClaims.get().then(function(response) {
   console.log(response); // logs ["foo", "bar"]
});
```

Tested and working. You will want to create a get method that simply returns the data instead of setting it first.

Comment: Just tried this method, and the featureClaims variable is returning back an empty [] after being set successfully

Comment: I updated my response with a working example. Hope that helps.

Comment: As a note in a real app I call the .init() function in the applications run phase so it's already setup as soon as the app launches. You can also set a default value there and update it in your controllers later.

Comment: still no luck, did you manage to get it working when  including the featureClaims factory in another service? I've updated my original post, with what I got so far

Comment: Change your get function to return a promise:  return $q.when(featureClaims.claims); and in your controller use .then(function(response) { // do stuff }). Services normally return promises as the data you're requesting my not be available instantaneously.

Comment: The then callback is returning back an undefined after calling the featureClaims.get(). post updated with latest code